# jQuery - Waiting 2 seconds before hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

So, in my code the function is supposed to make #aboutPopOut slide to the left and then after 2 seconds, the fadescreen to .hide(). The sliding works, but the waiting and hiding does not. Here is my function;

```
function aboutHide() {
    $("#aboutPopOut").animate({ left: "-60%" }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#fadeScreen").wait(2).hide();
    }, 500);
};
```

Please help me figure out what is wrong. All responses will be appreciated.

Comment: What led you to believe that jQuery has a `wait()` method?

Comment: I sometimes script in lua, which has a wait() method. What does jQuery have instead of wait()?

Comment: JavaScript has `setTimeout()`. jQuery has `.delay()` but it won't work unless you queue the `.hide()` operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
function aboutHide() {
    $("#aboutPopOut").animate({ left: "-60%" }, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#fadeScreen").delay(2000).hide();
    }, 500);
};
```

Comment: Must be put in queue: `$("#fadeScreen").delay(2000).hide(0);`

Comment: This shouldn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/unuD5/.

Comment: Others are right. This should not work. Also, instead of a `setTimeout`, it would be more idiomatic jQuery to use a callback to the `.animate()` call, though that's another topic. But since `setTimeout` was being used anyway, they could just change `500` to `2500`.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [`.delay` method](https://api.jquery.com/delay/). You also have to pass a number to `.hide` to make it an animation method, otherwise `.delay` has no effect.

```
 $("#fadeScreen").delay(2000).hide(0);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Hide must be queued for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Update the following..

```
function aboutHide() {
$("#aboutPopOut").animate({ left: "-60%" }, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
$("#fadeScreen").delay(2000).hide();
}, 500);
};
```